# What python linter can I use to spot Python 2-3 compatibility issues?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8, flake8

I want to migrate a Python codebase to work in both Python 2 and Python 3 and I was surprised to see that by default tools like flake8 or pep8 missed a very simple use of print without parentheses (`print 1` instead of `print(1)`).

How can I ease this migration?

Comment: https://python-future.org/automatic_conversion.html Commit your code to source control, then run that. I wouldn't just trust its changes blindly, but it will identify most (all?) of the problem areas. With your code in source control, you can review what it changed. Also, use the `__future__` imports as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You should use 2to3 to spot issues/incompatibilities in the code

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html